# What is the real thing behind google blocked port 25?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall

I have read lot of documents related to the webmail is blocked on port 25 from google cloud firewall rules.
finally their always recommended to use third parties services? so my question is What is the real thing behind google blocked port 25?

If someone know the point to solve this problem please share!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not network services. [Superuser](https://superuser.com) might be a better place to ask about this, but I'm not sure I understand your question -- is it about why they block port 25 (it's to limit spamming, and [many providers do it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques#Port_25_blocking)), or how to send mail despite the block, or what?

Comment: This question is about Google Cloud Platform and sending email from VM instances. I don't think that [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) is suitable for such questions. Meanwhile, I'd recommend you next time post such questions at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find explanation in documentation [using standard email ports](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail#using_standard_email_ports):

> Due to the risk of abuse, connections to destination TCP Port 25 **are always blocked** when the destination is external to your VPC network. This includes using SMTP relay with Google Workspace.
>
> Google Cloud does not place any restrictions on traffic sent to external destination IP addresses using destination TCP ports 587 or 465. The implied allow egress firewall rule allows this traffic unless you've created egress deny firewall rules that block it.

You cannot use Firewall Rules to enable port 25, but you can use Google Workspace or 3rd party software like  [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [MailGun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet) to send e-mails.

You can't set up mail server on GCE VM instance because port 25 is still in use by majority of mail servers for communication between them accordingly with [RFC 821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-44). From [From SMTP RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321):

> **4.5.4.2.  Receiving Strategy**
>
> The SMTP server SHOULD attempt to keep a pending listen on the SMTP
> port (specified by IANA as port 25) at all times.  This requires the
> support of multiple incoming TCP connections for SMTP.  Some limit
> MAY be imposed, but servers that cannot handle more than one SMTP
> transaction at a time are not in conformance with the intent of this
> specification.
>
> As discussed above, when the SMTP server receives mail from a
> particular host address, it could activate its own SMTP queuing
> mechanisms to retry any mail pending for that host address.

The ports 587 and 465 are available for SMTP Message Submission ([RFC 6409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6409)). This means you can use an external mail relay (your own or from someone else) for authenticated SMTP, and this server handles delivery to other mail systems on port 25.